# ipRefererBlocked when accessing Youtube Data API

Tags: amazon-web-services, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

As of about 1PM CST yesterday, we are no longer able to use the Youtube Data API from our servers on AWS. We now receive the following response to every request from the cloud:

```
curl "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=GO5G-funzPI&key=OUR_API_KEY&part=contentDetails"
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "ipRefererBlocked",
    "message": "There is a per-IP or per-Referer restriction configured on your API key and the request does not match these restrictions. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your API key configuration if request from this IP or referer should be allowed.",
    "extendedHelp": "https://console.developers.google.com"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "There is a per-IP or per-Referer restriction configured on your API key and the request does not match these restrictions. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your API key configuration if request from this IP or referer should be allowed."
 }
}
```

When I look in the developer console, this project's API key does **not** have an IP address restriction. We tried whitelisting both the external IP and the internal IP range in the developer console, but it had no effect. The whitelisted ranges have now been removed, but the same message is still received within AWS.

This message is not received when using the same API key outside of AWS; if I run it from my machine either at my home or on our office network I get the expected video data returned:

```
curl "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=GO5G-funzPI&key=OUR_API_KEY&part=contentDetails"
{
 "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
 "etag": "\"kuL0kDMAqRo3pU7O0pwlO-Lfzp4/Qye0F1aiqHjVYlPPicUgbMvEoOQ\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1,
  "resultsPerPage": 1
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#video",
   "etag": "\"kuL0kDMAqRo3pU7O0pwlO-Lfzp4/wMAduvfW4vn2Up8MEhRCbpCtY-w\"",
   "id": "GO5G-funzPI",
   "contentDetails": {
    "duration": "PT28S",
    "dimension": "2d",
    "definition": "sd",
    "caption": "true",
    "licensedContent": true
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

Any ideas? This is run in our CMS backend to scrape title, image, and description from youtube videos when loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible that the API key type you have selected wasn't appropriate for the traffic being received. This doesn't appear to be a firewall/communication issue since it's providing a 403 error, so that can be ignroed. Can you generate a new key for the server and see if that resolves the problem from that particular IP?

On a separate note, what type of key was originally created for this project?

Comment: Not a proper way to post your comment, whether you have sufficient reputation or not.

Comment: Creating a new key for this project ultimately solved the problem. Thanks Adam!